# Error when deploying Experience Bundle with new route and view

Tags: experience-cloud, experience-bundle

I'm trying to deploy experience bundles that I retrieved from one sandbox to another. There's one new route and view. Deployment fails with this error:

`The AppPageId in <path to route>.json doesn't have a valid ComponentId. Check your file and try again`.

The appPageId is identical with the same attribute of the corresponding view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you omit the new route+view from the main deployment and then deploy it later, or are there dependencies that require it?